# Convert JSON to comma-separated list in SQL Server with OPENJSON

Tags: json, sql-server, open-json

In SQL Server 2016, I am trying to convert the following JSON:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @json = 
N' {
        "date": "2021-12-31",
        "distributor_name": "Test",

        "movies": [
            {
                "category_id": 3,
                "name": "Dune",
                "budget": 165,
                "release_date": "2021-09-03",

                "location": [
                    {
                        "location_type": 1, 
                        "location_code": "US"
                    },
                    {
                        "location_type": 2,
                        "location_code": "CA"
                    },
                    {
                        "location_type": 2,
                        "location_code": "UK"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "category_id": 2,
                "name": "No Time to Die",
                "budget": 250,
                "release_date": "2021-09-28",
                
                "location": [
                    {
                        "location_type": 1, 
                        "location_code": "US"
                    },
                    {
                        "location_type": 1, 
                        "location_code": "UK"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
';
```

into:

| category_id | name | budget | release_date | country | distribution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Dune | 165 | 2021-09-03 | US | CA, UK |
| 2 | No Time to Die | 250 | 2021-09-28 | US, UK | NULL |

What should be added to the following statement to ensure that all `location_code` with `location_type = 1` go under `country` in a comma-separated list format, and all `location_code` with `location_type = 2` go under `distribution` in a comma-separated list format.

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.movies')
  WITH (
    category_id INT '$.category_id',
    name VARCHAR(255) '$.name',
    budget INT '$.budget',
    release_date DATE '$.release_date'
  )
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky 13.0.5888.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OPENJSON` a second time in a subquery to break out the inner `location` array.

For SQL Server 2016, you need to use `FOR XML` to aggregate.

```sql
DECLARE @sep varchar(10) = ',';

SELECT
  j.category_id,
  j.name,
  j.budget,
  j.release_date,
  country = STUFF((
      SELECT
        @sep + location_code
      FROM OPENJSON(j.location)
        WITH (
          location_type int,
          location_code char(2)
        ) j2
      WHERE j2.location_type = 1
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]','varchar(max)'), 1, LEN(@sep), ''),
  distribution = STUFF((
      SELECT
        @sep + location_code
      FROM OPENJSON(j.location)
        WITH (
          location_type int,
          location_code char(2)
        ) j2
      WHERE j2.location_type = 2
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]','varchar(max)'), 1, LEN(@sep), '')
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.movies')
  WITH (
    category_id int,
    name nvarchar(200),
    budget int,
    release_date datetime,
    location nvarchar(max) AS JSON
  ) j;
```

Later versions can use `STRING_AGG` much more simply:

```sql
SELECT
  j.category_id,
  j.name,
  j.budget,
  j.release_date,
  country = (
      SELECT STRING_AGG(j2.location_code, ',')
      FROM OPENJSON(j.location)
        WITH (
          location_type int,
          location_code char(2)
        ) j2
      WHERE j2.location_type = 1
  ),
  distribution = (
      SELECT STRING_AGG(j2.location_code, ',')
      FROM OPENJSON(j.location)
        WITH (
          location_type int,
          location_code char(2)
        ) j2
      WHERE j2.location_type = 2
  )
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.movies')
  WITH (
    category_id int,
    name nvarchar(200),
    budget int,
    release_date datetime,
    location nvarchar(max) AS JSON
  ) j;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=faf0322049e6327b689d0f156fec852f)